# getting the row corresponding to the max of other row

Tags: sql

I have a table `TAB` having two fields `A` and `B`, `A` is a `Varchar2(50)` and `B` is a `Date`.

Supposing we have these values:

```
 A  |      B
------------------
 a1 | 01-01-2013
 a2 | 05-05-2013
 a3 | 06-06-2013
 a4 | 04-04-2013
```

we need to have the value of field `A` corresponding to the maximum of field `B`, that is mean that we need to return `a3`.

I made this request:

```
select A 
from TAB 
where 
B = (select max(B) from TAB)
```

but I want to avoid nested select like in this solution.

Have you an idea about the solution ?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153819/how-to-select-only-row-with-max-sequence-without-using-a-subquery

Comment: In case you're using MySQL, I elaborated in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358578/whats-the-canonical-way-to-pull-a-record-from-a-mysql-database-that-has-a-least why your way of doing it is actually not bad. Note that my answer there is especially for group-wise maximums. If you don't have groups, it's easiest to do like Manoj wrote in his answer.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using, ktaria? My comment above should actually be valid for other RDBMSs, too.

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER and ORACLE 11g

Comment: it does not work fine @mhasan !!it return more than one line !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d8e6/6/3) where I listed 4 different ways to achieve what you want. Note, that I added another row to your example. So you have two rows with the maximum date. See the difference between the queries? Manoj's way will give you just one row, although 2 rows match the criteria. You can click on "View execution plan" to see the difference how SQL Server handles these queries.

The 4 different ways (written in standard SQL, they should work with every RDBMS):

```
select A 
from TAB 
where 
B = (select max(B) from TAB);


select top 1 * from tab order by b desc;


select 
*
from
tab t1
left join tab t2 on t1.b < t2.b
where t2.b is null;


select
*
from
tab t1
inner join (
  select max(b) as b from tab
  ) t2 on t1.b = t2.b;
```

and here two more ways especially for SQL Server thanks to a_horse_with_no_name:

```
select *
from (
  select a, 
         b,
         rank() over (order by b desc) as rnk  
  from tab
) t
where rnk = 1;

select *
from (
  select a,
         b, 
         max(b) over () as max_b
  from tab
) t
where b = max_b;
```

See them working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d8e6/21).

Comment: it works fine with the fourth solution, thank you very much

Comment: Glad to hear that it works. I find it kind of strange, though that not all solutions work for you.

Comment: There are two more ways: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d8e6/21

Comment: Thanks, I edited them into my answer.

Comment: @ktaria Two more ways have been added, ktaria.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way also

```
SELECT TOP 1 A FROM TAB ORDER BY B DESC
```

Thanks

Manoj

Comment: Manoj, it is not wright like this, it does not return the good value

Comment: Are you sure, ktaria? It definitely should work. Only explanation is, that your column B is not of type date (is it varchar by any chance?) or you made a copy&paste error.

Comment: Well, ktaria, this will provide you proper value as per your requirement. Let me know what kind of problem u r facing with this ?

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for you...try it

```
SELECT TOP 1 A,B FROM TAB ORDER BY B DESC
```