# SQL get the closest row for a certain date in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having a table `TAB_A`:

```
  ID  |    Date    |   Value  
--------------------------------
  101 | 2014-03-01 | 101000001
  101 | 2014-03-03 | 101000003
  101 | 2014-03-06 | 101000006
  102 | 2014-03-01 | 102000001
  103 | 2014-03-01 | 103000001
```

And, for example, this single record in another table `TAB_B`:

```
    ID  |    Date    |  TAB_A.Id 
-----------------------------------
  40002 | 2014-03-05 |     101
```

**I need to get the closest (most *recent*) `TAB_A.Value` to `TAB_B.Date` field** (which in this case would be '101000003' and NOT '101000006').

I've been searching for other responses with similar scenarios (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153819/how-to-select-only-row-with-max-sequence-without-using-a-subquery)), but this is not exactly what I need.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that `TAB_A` has over 200K records and `TAB_B` has over 55M records.

Comment: what would your expected Value be with the date 2014-03-02 in tab_b ? Do you have any indexes ? With all those rows I would expect you have some indexes that we could use in our answers

Comment: Expected TAB_A value for TAB_B '2014-03-02' would be 101000001, since it's the most recent -past- value for that ID.
This table has not any indexes yet, but I'm planning to add some (Date field claims for one, obviously).

Comment: but there are 3 different Values for 2014-03-01. There are no matching id between the 2 tables

Comment: Oh yes you're right. Sorry, I was trying to simplify the table, which actually is much more complex than that one. I should have included a 'TAB_A.Id' field in TAB_B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seeing as the tag is sql-server, `Limit` won't work. Instead, use top

```
 SELECT TOP 1 ID, Date, Value 
 FROM TAB_A 
 WHERE Date < (SELECT Date from TAB_B where ID=40002) 
 ORDER BY Date DESC
```

or

```
 SELECT  ID, Date, Value 
 FROM tab_a
 WHERE date=
 (SELECT MAX(date) 
  FROM TAB_A 
  WHERE Date < 
     (SELECT Date 
    FROM TAB_B 
    WHERE ID=40002)
 )
```

If you want just 1 result in the last query, use `DISTINCT`. For example, if the date you were looking for is 2014-03-01, the 2nd query would show you 3 examples, with distinct just 1. In the first query, `top 1` already ensures that you just have 1 result
.

EDIT: updated for the comment below:

```
SELECT b.id, b.date, a.value FROM
    (SELECT TOP 1 ID, Date, Value 
     FROM TAB_A 
     WHERE Date < (SELECT Date from TAB_B B where ID=40002) 
     ORDER BY Date DESC) a
     ,
     (SELECT id,date,[TAB_A.id] FROM tab_b )b
     WHERE a.id=b.[TAB_A.id]
```

Excuse my capital letters/small letters inconsistency...

Comment: This definitely answers my question regarding single queries. I'm wondering how could I join the two tables, in order to get a TAB_B.Id, TAB_B.Date, TAB_A.Value schema.

Comment: Thanks user1261104. It throws an error:
"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Comment: Just as in the other query, if you want it to return just 1 row, use `Distict` , so line 4 becomes `WHERE Date < (SELECT Distinct Date from TAB_B B where ID=40002)`

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. Unfortunately I'm getting just the same error although I use Distinct.

Comment: That's weird. I managed to indeed het the error, but fixed it with `distinct`, as the subquery in line 4 is the only part that may not have multple results because it's behind the `<`. At least that's what I thought...

Comment: @HiseaSaw did you try my answer at all ? I does exactly as you requested and joins your tables. I am still puzzles as to why I was the one who didn't get upvoted

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, Date, Value 
FROM TAB_A 
WHERE Date < (SELECT Date from TAB_B where ID=40002) 
ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1
```

First you select this date which you need from TAB_B in a subquery. Then you select all these dates that are earlier than this from TAB_B (you can modify to <= if you need). Then you order descending by date and select TOP 1 (the highest one). I think that you could also use MAX (but I am not sure).

Comment: Limit is not valid in sql-server

Comment: In SQL Server I would use SELECT TOP 1. +1 for you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (
SELECT A.ID,A.Value, MIN(DATEDIFF(day,A.Date,B.Date)) as MinDiff
FROM TAB_A A, TAB_B B
GROUP BY A.ID,A.Value ) as T 
WHERE MinDiff>0
ORDER BY MinDiff
```

Result:

```
ID    VALUE       MINDIFF
101   101000003   2
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2159e/31).

**Explanation:**

Inner query will select ID,Value and minimum date difference. With the outer query, we can select the record having minimum date difference which is greater than 0.

Comment: your select will perform really slow. It will cause an out or memory with these tables

Answer (score 0):

The following code will show the first record for the given condition.In your case it will return what u needed..!

> ```
> SELECT Value 
>   FROM TAB_A 
>   WHERE DATE < (SELECT Date from TAB_B WHERE ID= '40002') and ROWNUM <= 1 
>   ORDER BY DATE;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should have an index on date in tab_a for this to perform well (requires sqlserver 2008+):

```
declare @tab_a table(id int, Date date, value int)
insert @tab_a values (101,'2014-03-01',101000001),
(101,'2014-03-03',101000003),(101,'2014-03-06',101000006),
(102,'2014-03-01',102000001),(103,'2014-03-01',103000001)

declare @tab_b table(id int, Date date, tab_a_id int)
insert @tab_b
values
(  40002, '2014-03-05', 101 ), (  40002, '2014-03-02', 101 )

select b.ID, b.Date bdate, x.Date adate, x.value
from @tab_b b
outer apply
(select top 1 value, date
from @tab_a a
where a.date <= b.date
and a.id = b.TAB_A_Id
order by a.date desc
) x
```

Result:

```
ID    bdate       adate     value
40002 2014-03-05 2014-03-03 101000003
40002 2014-03-02 2014-03-01 101000001
```